# Docker - Running Container but can’t view app in browser

Tags: docker, configuration, docker-for-mac

Following the getting started docs outlined [here](http://docs.sitestacker.com/articles/get-started-with-site-stacker#clone-site-stacker) I have decided to run the same environment but with the new Docker for Mac app. The docs say that after running the commands I should be able to go to 192.168.99.100/admin to login but I am not able to pull anything up. I think this is because the app was configured with docker tool box which used a VM ip of the one mentioned above. Doing localhost:80 I get the apps error and favicon, please what am I doing wrong I am new to docker and developing with these new tools.

Comment: as @Pixelartist says, your question has too many missing pieces of info. Think about those who will read it and try to figure it out. If you redirect us to some blog, most of us will just not bother. Beside, you're not really following the steps exactly as you're saying. Start by including the actual commands that you're typing, one after another. Lines of code/commands is much better than long descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

your questions leaves a lot of room for errors - I will try to answer it as simple as possible.

How to identify you docker IP on a mac - depending on the method you are using:

- boot2docker `boot2docker ip`
- docker-machine `docker-machine ip default`
- If you were using kitematic - check the tool

In case this does not work, check your docker container (`docker ps` for the ID) by using `docker inspect`which will reveal the information you need if you find the Keyword **IPAdress**.

In case it still feels it should run but does not - check with a default docker container like nginx ( `docker run --name docker-nginx -p 80:80 nginx` )